# Unexpected error while reading and writing excel file Using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: excel, junit, selenium-webdriver

I am using this method to read

```
FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\GChaitanya.CHAINGANG\\Desktop\\2012_October_3PL_Unified_Template.xls");
Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(fi);
s = w.getSheet(0);
```

And this to write

```
WritableWorkbook wb = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("D:\\output_2.xls"));
WritableSheet ws = wb.createSheet("customsheet", 1);
```

I get this error

```
org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Command duration or timeout: 100.10 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '2.34.0', revision: '11cd0ef', time: '2013-08-06 17:11:28'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Session ID: 60c039f3-60bb-413f-aca5-0543e074b04e
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, databaseEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserName=firefox, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=24.0}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:79)
    at gmailTest.TestLink.RealTime(TestLink.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Build info: version: '2.34.0', revision: '11cd0ef', time: '2013-08-06 17:11:28'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.cache.getElementAt(resource://fxdriver/modules/web_element_cache.js:7642)
    at <anonymous class>.Utils.getElementAt(file:///C:/Users/GCHAIT~1.CHA/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous5288729173687770784webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:7231)
    at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.preconditions.visible(file:///C:/Users/GCHAIT~1.CHA/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous5288729173687770784webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:8228)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_(file:///C:/Users/GCHAIT~1.CHA/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous5288729173687770784webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10799)
    at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Users/GCHAIT~1.CHA/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous5288729173687770784webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10816)
    at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify(file:///C:/Users/GCHAIT~1.CHA/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous5288729173687770784webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:396)
```

and shows this in debug mode

```
<terminated, exit value: 0>C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe (Oct 29, 2013 5:12:25 PM)
```

The code was working fine but stopped working all of a sudden it hardly read 10 records and crashes. I was able to read at least 300 to 400 records

Comment: `org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache` this error is something related to the WebElement in the Application you are working upon. Can you check the line in java code at which you are getting this error?

Comment: At this line is the real bug: `gmailTest.TestLink.RealTime(TestLink.java:100)`

Comment: The code shown has *absolutely nothing to do* with the error because the code shown has *absolutely nothing to do* with Selenium. Please check the stack trace and post what is *actually* error'ing.

Answer (score 0):

```
package realDatatesting;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
//import java.io.IOException;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.write.Label;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;
import java.io.File;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
//import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
//import com.google.common.collect.Table.Cell;
public class Realtime_snap{
Sheet s;
WebDriver driver;
@Before
public void setUp()
{
 driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
/**
* @throws Exception
*/
@Test
public void RealTime() throws Exception
{

driver.get("----URl---");

//Passing the user name and password
driver.findElement(By.id("-----")).sendKeys("-----");
driver.findElement(By.id("-------")).sendKeys("------");
//Clicking on login button
driver.findElement(By.id("-------")).click();

//Selecting real time estimator
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='nav']/li[3]/a")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='nav']/li[3]/ul/li[2]/a")).click();


//Selecting model
driver.findElement(By.xpath("----")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("------")).click();

FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("---Filepath");
Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(fi);
s = w.getSheet(0);
int totalrows=s.getRows();
for(int row=31; row < totalrows;row++)
{
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    s = w.getSheet(0);
    WritableWorkbook wb = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("D:\\output1.xls"));
    WritableSheet ws = wb.createSheet("customsheet", 1);


    Thread.sleep(1000);
    String origin = s.getCell(1,row).getContents();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("----")).sendKeys(origin);

    .
            .
            .
    String TempCont = s.getCell(13,row).getContents();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("------")).sendKeys(TempCont);

    //Click's on calculate button
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("------")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);



        String m1 = (driver.findElement(By.id("------")).getText());
        Label label1 = new Label(1, row, m1);
        ws.addCell(label1);

      .
      .
      .

        String m17 = (driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderBody_ucModelDataEntry1_lblRegionalVariability")).getText());
        Label Label17 = new Label(18, row, m17);
        ws.addCell(Label17);
      //Click on Reset
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderBody_ucModelDataEntry1_resetBtn']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    //Clicking on logout

     wb.write();                                                            

        wb.close();

}

} 



@After
public void tearDown() throws InterruptedException
{
Thread.sleep(10000);        
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".-----")).click();
driver.close();
driver.quit();
}
}
```

This the whole code which was working fine i dont understand what went wrong tried many methods but none worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the error related to Reading or writing Excel file. You are getting error (StaleElementReferenceException) with click on a web element using Selenium at following line

**at gmailTest.TestLink.RealTime(TestLink.java:100)**

Before clicking webelement, make sure the element has the valid latest reference.

see about StaleElementReferenceException 
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp

Comment: Hi,Thank you for the reply 
and this very code was working and stopped all the and yes i have verified that the reference of the elements are right.
As i mentioned they run some 10-20 runs and then stop.
Can you please guide me what else might be wrong